# What shape does an elastic rod take when both ends are dragged to the same point?

Tags: elasticity

Suppose we have an ideal elastic rod of some kind, where the energy at a point along the rod is proportional to the square of the curvature, and we drag the ends of this rod so that they touch, and the rest of the rod is now making some kind of teardrop shape off to one side.
Like this:
[image: The rod is bent so that the ends touch]
Is there an equation for the exact shape the rod will take?

I think another way to approximate this is by dragging two opposite edges to touch and seeing the shape the cross-section of the paper takes.

I apologize if this question isn't very clear. I'm not familiar with the official terminology in this field.

Comment: Do you mean what happens when you pinch a rubber band? Perhaps a photo/drawing would help

Comment: Neat question.  The answer will depend on the angle of contact.  In the extreme case where the flat ends are in full contact you obviously get a circle ( O-ring).  I'm not quite sure how you can get the angle to be zero without applying a pinching force and thus having a line-segment contact region.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The angle is whatever the ends want to be at. Imagine we're sticking pins in the ends and dragging them like that so they can still rotate freely. The thickness of the rod is negligible, so we don't have to worry about its effect on the final shape. That's why I brought up the paper example.

Comment: It’s going to depend on what you mean by “elastic.” A search term is [buckling instability](https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/me471/thompson/handout/class07_2005S_Buckling.pdf). I suspect, but haven’t shown, that quadratic deformation energy $U=\frac12 k\Delta x^2$ is minimized if the curvature of the rod is constant, which would make a circle.

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in the pure bending equation and its derivation. http://emweb.unl.edu/negahban/em325/11-Bending/Bending.htm

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the rod is inextensible and elastic with an elastic energy proportional to the square of the curvature, the curve you are looking for is a particular case of [Euler's elastica](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2008/EECS-2008-103.pdf). Therein, check equation (12) with the parameters given for the "lemnoid" and Euler's figure (8). See also [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/linteaire/linteaire.shtml), the case of the pseudo-lemniscate.

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you present you already know the shape of the deformed configuration. If you compute a parameterization from the original configuration to the deformed one you would get "an equation". Now, I would guess that, in general, this displacement field would not satisfy equilibrium and it would need a body force to obtain such a shape.

If your equation is referring to the case where you have the flat case and you want to apply forces/displacements on the extremes to obtain a shape that is close to the one that you are showing, then you would need so solve for a non-linear partial differential equation subject to some boundary conditions. I general, you can't solve these differential equations analytically and you need a numerical methods such as the finite element method.

Comment: This is a comment rather than a quantitative answer

Comment: I don't know the final shape. The diagram only has a crude representation of what I expect the final shape to be like.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This partial answer is correctly posted as an answer.

Comment: @zucculent, do you know the boundary conditions then?

Answer (score 0):

By Euler-Bennoulli Law,

$$ \kappa= \frac{M}{EI}=\frac{d\phi}{ds}=\frac{F y}{EI}=\frac{y}{c^2}$$

where $\kappa$ is curvature, $\phi$ slope, $M$ bending moment proportional to $y$ coordinate, $EI$ flexural rigidity, $F$ are two equal opposite forces applied at towards origin along x-axis and $c= \sqrt{EI/F},$ a length constant.

The deformations are elastic. the elastic rod rebounds back to original straight shape on removal of $Fs$.

$$ \frac{dy}{ds}=\sin \phi ;\;\frac{dx}{ds}=\cos\phi ;$$

The Elasticas are three types: progressive, regressive, stationary closed loop shapes which are relevant to this question.

The ode is intrinsic.

$$ \frac{d^2\phi}{ds^2}= \frac{\sin \phi}{c^2}$$

The deformed elastic shapes can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals in closed form solutions, not given here. The numerical solution of ode for closed loops finds an approximate relation between loop length $smax$ and $c$ given here by trial and error,$(10,2.514)$ respectively for closed loops.

The semi-loops  are all geometrically similar and are capable of being defined using this specific $c/smax =0.2514 $ ratio obtained on `Mathematica`.. as a Boundary Value Problem.

[image]

EDIT1:

Taking the following ode

$$\phi'(s)=\frac{2 r(s)}{a^2}$$

with BCs $a=\sqrt 2,  c=1, \phi_{initial}=0.86053 $

and ode used $r$ in place of $y$

$$ \cos \phi=\frac{c^2-r^2(s)}{a^2} $$

still using trial/error $\phi_{initial}\; $  value we get one closed loop using code given below.

[image]